# Build entire iOS app as a website?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

This might be a silly question, but wondering if I was able to build an iOS app completely in a UIWebview.  Essentially not have one thing be native to iOS.

Comment: You could, but you risk rejection due to [App Store Review Guideline 2.12](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#functionality): “ Apps that are not very useful, unique, **are simply web sites bundled as Apps**, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected”. Also, your app will probably suck.

Comment: `"Essentially not have one thing be native to iOS"` - Well you'd have a `UIWebView` so you'd have at least one thing native to iOS. Agee with `rob mayoff` your app would suck if you did this. There is absolutely nothing stopping you from doing it but if you want your app in the app store then I'd rethink your design (See `rob mayoff's` comment for why) .

Comment: Thanks Rob.  The app is under development but wanted to push something out immediately.

Comment: *cough* `WKWebView`: "For new development, employ this class instead of the older `UIWebView` class."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually. There are several ways to use HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript to make mobile apps like iOS. You can use frameworks/programs like Cordova/PhoneGap. These frameworks/programs can let you use web languages and then compile it into an executable for the device. Something that can be submitted to the AppStore. Whether or not Apple accepts it thats another story. ;)

The other thing you can do is you want it to completely run off the web is you can essentially build a web app on a server like any other web app. However, you can put in CSS3 media queries and Javascript that can detect the size of the screen. Users can use their built in web browsers to access your site. If the screen isn't the right size, then you can redirect the user like if they try to access it with a laptop. With this method you can use server side scripting languages like PHP to do your computation processing. However, connection is required to the server and if a whole lot of people log in to your server, then the server can get bog down.

If you are interested in using web base languages for mobile applications, I highly suggest looking into PhoneGap/Cordova.